# How to have a private key when using Firebase Admin SDK in Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

We are currently deploying and developing an application created in Laravel on GAE.
We are using Firebase-Admin-SDK in that app, and we store and use the Firebase-Admin-SDK private key in the Credential folder in the project.
When we deploy to GAE, we deploy the private key together with the application.
I would like to know if anyone knows a good way to do this from a security standpoint.

Comment: What kind of private key? If you mean a service account JSON key file, then you should not use one at all because that is a security risk. Secrets should not be part of your application deployment files/package. You can fetch tokens (access and identity) from the App Engine Metadata service. [Link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#metadata_server) with examples in PHP. If you mean something else, edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Also, consider storing the service account JSON in Secrets Manager.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
You are correct that the private key is a JSON file.

I understand that JSON private keys should not be used.
I appreciate it because I was very troubled.

Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You can use service account JSON key files. Just think about the security of those types of files. The cool thing about Google Cloud is that there are secure alternatives that often are easier to implement and manage.

Comment: The JSON key file must be stored and used in the Secret Manager if used.

If not, the token is obtained from the AppEngine metadata and then used in the AppEngine metadata,
If not, then the token is obtained from AppEngine metadata and the service account is used, is that correct?

Comment: When asking questions like this, it is important to clearly define the environment and use case. For example, you have not shown what the service account is used for. I am guessing that you want to use the service account to authorize the Firebase Admin SDK. In that case, base64 encode the entire file and store the contents as a string in Secret Manager. The app then retrieves the string, base64 decodes it, and stores the contents as a file within your application. That file is then used to authorize the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: You can also use another secure service like Cloud Storage to store the service account file. For my projects, I have a special project and bucket that has tight authorization where I store certain types of secrets. In other cases, I only use the compute service metadata server. The implementation, level of security, and CI/CD method determine which method I select.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.
In this case, we will store the JSON key file in the SecretManager and
I would like to respond to this issue.